# Is there a way to tell if a file has changed in the Windows API other than opening it or timestamps?

Tags: windows, file, last-modified

I'm writing a program which needs to look at a very large number of files, some of which are very large in size.  I'd like to visit a file only once, unless it changes.  If it changes I need to revisit it again.

The way I know of to do this is with datestamps.  One can look at the modified date to see if it is newer than the last time you looked at the file.  Obviously those can be changed programmatically, so I'm wondering if there is a way to determine if a file has changed other than that.  (I'm thinking along the lines of a UUID for the file which is changed every time it is modified or an epoch counter, but I'm open to more exotic solutions)

Comment: The OS provides no sucn functionality. The common way to do this is to calculate a CRC value and store it. To see if the file changed, you calculate a new CRC and see if it's the same as the previous one.

Comment: @KenWhite Well drat.  If you post that as an answer (since it is one), I'll accept it if nobody finds an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor changes for these files, assuming you continue to run the whole time. Check the FindFirstChangeNotification API. You can take a look at [this project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4692/How-to-get-a-notification-if-change-occurs-in-a-sp) as an example. Sysinternals also has a similar tool, I believe it's implemented in a similar way.